# Eclipse Mylyn Active Task context and Git commiting

Tags: eclipse, git, mylyn

I've lost like 2 hours for finding a solution, with no success.
I have installed Mylyn (3.9.1) and EGit (3.1.0) in my Eclipse (Kepler 4.3.1).

Window->Preferences->Mylyn->Team has checked "Automatically create and manage with task context" and has a "Commit Comment Template" defined.

Window->Preferences->Team->Git->Commit Dialog has no options that might be corresponding with this kind of synchronization.

So why, when i working with "Active" task and trying to make Git Commit, I dont see Task title, number etc like a default commit message ?

I've this functionality some time ago on another machine and eclipse, but dont know what to do here.

I've tried to reinstall all Mylyn with no success.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install "Task focused interface for Eclipe Git Team Provider", which should be on the preinstalled Eclipse update site.

For Kepler:

- Help | Install new Software...
- Select "Kepler - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler"
- Search for "Task focused interface for Eclipe Git Team Provider"
- Go throught the install process as usual.